# How can I query for rows with latest date and do an inner join on a second table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

All the examples I've seen show how to do an inner join using an alias to get rows with the latest date. I can do that with my data but I also want to do an inner join on another table and can't figure how to do both with the same query.

Here are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `titleID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titlename` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `category` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `postdate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`titleID`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  CONSTRAINT `titles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`catid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `statid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `views` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `favs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedate` date NOT NULL,
  `title` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`statid`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  CONSTRAINT `stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`title`) REFERENCES `titles` (`titleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My goals:

1) I want a query that gives me all the latest stats for each title.

2) I want to see the text name of the title (from the titles table).

I can use this query to get the latest score for each title.

```
select t.score, t.views, t.favs, t.comments, t.updatedate, t.title
from stats t 
inner join (
select title, max(updatedate) as updatedate 
from stats
GROUP BY title
) tm on t.title = tm.title and t.updatedate = tm.updatedate
```

But the problem with this query is that it displays the title column from stats which is an int. I want the text name of the title.

I can do this to get the title name and the score, but then I'm not getting the row with the latest date.

```
select titlename, score, updatedate
from stats
inner join titles
on titleid = title
```

How can I write a query that achieves both my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `title` table in this case as

```
select 
s1.score, 
s1.views, 
s1.favs, 
s1.comments, 
s1.updatedate, 
t.titlename
from titles t 
join stats s1 on s1.title = t.titleID
join (
 select title, max(updatedate) as updatedate 
 from stats
 GROUP BY title
) s2 on s2.title = s1.title and s1.updatedate = s2.updatedate
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abhik! You've given me the answer and lots to mull over.